# Не работает фильтрация

Tags: android-studio, listview, asp.net-web-api, filter

Делаю фильтрацию по listview, значения в него помещаю из api. Когда что-то ввожу в поиск listview очищается, если стереть, то listview остаётся пустым. Что здесь не так?

Каталог:

```
public class Catalog extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProductAdapter mAdapter;
private List<Product> mProductList = new ArrayList<>();
private ListView lvProduct;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_catalog);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(menuItem -> {
        if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_search) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0,0);
            return true;
        }

        if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_order) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Order.class));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            return true;
        }

        if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.navigation_catalog){

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });

    lvProduct = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mAdapter = new ProductAdapter(Catalog.this, mProductList);
    lvProduct.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    new GetProducts().execute();
}

private class GetProducts extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.102:3000/api/Product");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }
            return result.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        try {
            JSONArray tempArray = new JSONArray(s);
            for (int i = 0; i < tempArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject productJson = tempArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Product tempProduct = new Product(
                        productJson.getInt("Код"),
                        productJson.getString("Наименование"),
                        productJson.getString("Штрих_код"),
                        productJson.getString("Изображение"),
                        productJson.getString("Артикул"),
                        productJson.getString("Цена"),
                        productJson.getString("Стеллаж"),
                        productJson.getString("Проём")
                );
                mProductList.add(tempProduct);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.actionSearch);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText))
            {
                mAdapter.Filter("");
                lvProduct.clearTextFilter();
            }
            else
            {
                mAdapter.Filter(newText);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

}

Адаптер с фильтрацией (сократил):

```
private Context mcontext;
private List<Product> mProductList;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<Product> arrayList;
public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<Product> mProductList) {
    this.mcontext = context;
    this.mProductList = mProductList;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
    this.arrayList = new ArrayList<Product>();
    this.arrayList.addAll(mProductList);
}

public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    View v = View.inflate(mcontext, R.layout.item_product, null);

    ImageView imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewItem);
    TextView textName =  v.findViewById(R.id.textNameItem);
    TextView textBarcode =  v.findViewById(R.id.textViewBarcodeItem);
    TextView textPrice =  v.findViewById(R.id.textPriceItem);

    Product currentProduct = mProductList.get(i);   

    imageView.setImageBitmap(currentProduct.getBitmapSource());

    textName.setText(currentProduct.getName());

    textBarcode.setText(currentProduct.getBarcode());

    textPrice.setText(currentProduct.getPrice());


    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intentDetails = new Intent(mcontext, Details.class);
            intentDetails.putExtra("product", currentProduct);
            mcontext.startActivity(intentDetails);
        }
    });

    return v;
}

public void Filter(String charText){
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        mProductList.clear();

        if (charText.length() == 0)
        {
            mProductList.addAll(arrayList);
        }
        else
        {
            for (Product product : arrayList)
            {
                if(product.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))
                {
                    mProductList.add(product);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Меню:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/actionSearch"
    android:title="Поиск"
    android:icon="@drawable/baseline_search_24"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />
```